# Can't inherit explicit template specialization of same class in clang and gcc

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I want an `Iterable<T>` class to allow iterating generically on Object also. (T is assumed to be a derived of Object)
However when defining my generic `Iterable<T>` as inheriting the specialized version for Object `Iterable<Object>`, as soon as the class is instantiated, I get a compile error in both clang and gcc (but not in MSVC).
The error is that `Iterable<Object>` is an incomplete type.

First question is why, since I expected the compiler would use the explicit instantiation of Iterable there.
Second question is what would be a possible solution achieving the same result, the desired result being that an `Iterable<T>` with any T that is not Object should satisfy the IS A relationship with `Iterable<Object>`

```
#include <functional>

class Object
{};

class Foo : public Object
{};

template <class T>
class Iterable : public Iterable<Object>
{
public:
    virtual void iterate(const std::function<void(T&)>& callback) const = 0;
};

template <>
class Iterable<Object>
{
public:
    virtual void iterate(const std::function<void(Object&)>& callback) const = 0;
};
```

Comment: It is a kind of recursive definition. I mean, you are trying to specialize something for which the specialization is required..

Comment: `Iterable<Object>` is not dependent name

Comment: @perencia But I would expect the specialization doesn't rely on the general definition. What I understand you are saying is that it actually does ?

Answer (score 3):

You can easily solve this by declaring the primary template first, then specialising it, and then defining it:

```
template <class T>
class Iterable;

template <>
class Iterable<Object>
{
public:
    virtual void iterate(const std::function<void(Object&)>& callback) const = 0;
};

template <class T>
class Iterable : public Iterable<Object>
{
public:
    virtual void iterate(const std::function<void(T&)>& callback) const = 0;
};
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/11f289bfb6bf3302)

However, heed the warnings produced by the live example: `Iterable<T>::iterate` does not override `Iterable<Object>::iterate`, because their parameters have different types. You'll have to implement both in all classes derived from `Iterable<T>` for `T` other than `Object`.

Comment: Wow. I somehow assumed this wouldn't work. I thought the general definition was evaluated first regardless of the order. I'm very surprised to discover the order changes everything here. (And the declaration, but I already had that one as all my classes are forward declared.)
As for the warning in the actual code `Iterable<T>` implements the iterate function defined in `Iterable<Object>` so the warning isn't triggered.

Comment: @N0vember Order matters a lot in C++, *especially* with templates. Quoting C++11, [temp.expl.spec] 14.7.3/7 (emphasis mine): "The placement of explicit specialization declarations for function templates, class templates ... etc., can affect whether a program is
well-formed according to the relative positioning of the explicit specialization declarations and their points of
instantiation in the translation unit as specified above and below. **When writing a specialization, be careful
about its location; or to make it compile will be such a trial as to kindle its self-immolation.**"

Answer (score 1):

The error is occurring because you are inheriting from a class that has not been defined yet, so what you must do is define the class, and THEN define a specialization.  The compiler cannot instantiate a template that has not been defined yet.  You may find reading about the CRTP interesting.  See http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/05/17/the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-in-c.

To solve the problem that an object must satisfy the is-an-object criteria I would create an interface in object that encompasses everything it will be used for and create a non-template iterate function.  The whole point of templates is that they are generic and can be reused for unrelated types.

Comment: I know of the CRTP but I don't really see how it can help here, given my target of having a Iterable<T> being a Iterable<Object> when T is a derived of object.
However since you explained the underlying reason I tried to come up with a workaround in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer that I cannot use a specialization in the general definition, I tried to come-up with a workaround, and this is the best I currently see : feel free to propose nicer solutions.

```
template <class T, bool object = std::is_base_of<Object, T>::value>
class Iterable
{
public:
    virtual void iterate(const std::function<void(T&)>& callback) const = 0;
};

template <class T>
class Iterable<T, true> : public Iterable<Object>
{
public:
    virtual void iterate(const std::function<void(T&)>& callback) const = 0;
};
```

Comment: You can use specialization in general definition but the specialization that you are using must be dependent name depending on one of the template parameters. You could make compiler to treat `Iterable<Object>` as dependent name... See [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9390194c38dc83d2)

Comment: @W.F. Interesting. I'll prefer the top-rated answer since it's the cleanest and the simplest, but I learned something there.